# Count objects in array in an object in Frisby

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, frisby.js

I am starting to learn FrisbyJS and trying to create some assertions.

I get an json that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "articles": [
            {
                "article": "123-123002",
                "updated": "2016-10-20T14:57:25",
                "sourced balance": [],
                "balance": "50.00"
            },
            {
                "article": "100-123001",
                "updated": "2016-10-20T14:41:36",
                "sourced balance": [],
                "balance": "10.00"
            }
        ],
        "DistrictID": [],
        "WarehouseID": "SebastiansWarehouse",
        "SourceID": "1234",
        "City": "Stockholm",
        "WarehouseName": "Sebastians Warehouse",
        "WarehouseType": "STORE"
    }
]
```

And I want to:
 1. count the number of article objects
 2. verify that the number X in articles array has a variable with value "123-123002"

How can I do this in Frisby?

My code currently is:

```
var frisby = require('frisby');

frisby.create('Mekonomen RIF1')
  .get('https://10.254.8.67:9443/INTERSHOP/rest/WFS/Mekonomen-MekB2BSE-Site/-/availability/sources/1234/warehouses/SebastiansWarehouse/products/',{ strictSSL: false})
  .expectStatus(200)
.expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
.expectJSON('?',{
        articles: [],
        DistrictID: [],
        WarehouseID: "SebastiansWarehouse",
        SourceID: '1234',
        City: "Stockholm",
        WarehouseName: "Sebastians Warehouse",
        WarehouseType: "STORE"
    }
)
.expectJSON('?.articles',{
        articles: [],
        DistrictID: [],
        WarehouseID: "SebastiansWarehouse",
        SourceID: '1234',
        City: "Stockholm",
        WarehouseName: "Sebastians Warehouse",
        WarehouseType: "STORE"
    }
)
.expectMaxResponseTime(500)
.toss();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can include

`.afterJSON(json){
//json.articles can be asserted here
//some more assertion on the response
}`

which will parse the response and send it as an argument which can be asserted using simple javascript conditions, statements, loops etc.